# Prove: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k} = \binom{2n+1}{n}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, catalan-numbers

prove the following identity:

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k} = \binom{2n+1}{n}$

what I tried:

I figured that: $\displaystyle\binom{2n+1}{n} = (2n+1) C_n$
and $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}= \sum_{k=0}^{n}C_k\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}$

from here i tried simplifying:$\displaystyle\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}$ to something i could work with but did not succeed

I also know that $\displaystyle C_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}C_k C_{n-k-1}$ so I tried to prove : $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}C_k\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}= C_n + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}C_k\binom{2n-2k}{n-k} = C_n + 2n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}C_kC_{n-k-1}$ but that approach also failed (couldn't prove the last equality)

any suggestions?

Comment: would this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65944/proving-this-identity-sum-k-frac1k-binom2k-2k-1-binom2n-2k1n-k-b?rq=1

Comment: by $C_n$, do you mean $C^k_n$, i.e. $\binom{n}{k}$?

Comment: i mean the catlan number $C_n = \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$

Comment: See also: [Combinatorics Identity about Catalan numbers: $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k+1}\binom{2k}k \binom{2n-2k}{n-k}=\binom{2n+1}n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1533362#1533446)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s a combinatorial argument. $\binom{2n+1}n$ is the number of lattice paths from $\langle 0,0\rangle$ to $\langle n,n+1\rangle$ using $n$ right steps and $n+1$ up steps. Every such path must rise above the line $y=x$; let $\langle k,k+1\rangle$ be the first point at which it does so. There are $C_k=\frac1{k+1}\binom{2k}k$ paths from $\langle 0,0\rangle$ to $\langle k,k\rangle$ that do not rise above the line $y=x$, any of which can be combined with any of the $\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}$ unrestricted lattice paths from $\langle k,k+1\rangle$ to $\langle n,n+1\rangle$, so there are $\frac1{k+1}\binom{2k}k\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}$ paths from $\langle 0,0\rangle$ to $\langle n,n+1\rangle$ that first rise above the line $y=x$ at $\langle k,k+1\rangle$. Summing over $k$ yields the desired result.

Comment: It has been a great joy of reading your answers, Brian. I remember you said somewhere that you use angle brackets for sequences and round parenthesis for coordinates. Any reason why you use $\langle\ ,\ \rangle$ here?

Comment: @T.S: Thank you. I use angle brackets for ordered pairs, ordered $n$-tuples, and sequences generally, and that includes coordinates (though I may occasionally have slipped up in the past). It’s a convention that I picked up long ago from set theorists and continue to use because parentheses are heavily overburdened with different meanings.

Answer (score 4):

This is
$$\sum_{k=0}^n C_kA_{n-k}=B_n\tag{*}$$
where
$$C_n=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}{n},$$
$$A_n=\binom{2n}{n}$$
and
$$B_n=\binom{2n+1}{n}.$$
All we need to confirm (*) is to prove the generating function identity
$$C(x)A(x)=B(x)$$
where $A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n x^n$ etc.

But
$$C(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$$
and
$$A(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}$$
so that
$$C(x)A(x)=\frac1{2x\sqrt{1-4x}}-\frac12
=\frac12\sum_{m=1}^\infty\binom{2m}mx^{m-1}
=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n+2}{n+1}x^n$$
so all we now need is
$$\binom{2n+1}n=\frac12\binom{2n+2}{n+1}.$$